# Append to WP function in child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes, append

I have a Wordpress theme that has several functions I need to modify (through a child theme).  I'd rather not completely replace the function, in case it is updated in the future.  Is it possible to append code to a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to append code to a function.

Before all, I recommend you take take a look at the [Child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) documentation .

The behavior of the child theme will depend a lot on where you're editing your functions. If you're using functions.php, Wordpres states that:

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override
>   its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to
>   the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before
>   the parent’s file.)

So what you can do is to override the parent function, like stated [here](http://venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions):

1. Copy (in full) the function you want to override from the parent theme.
2. Paste it into functions.php in the root of your child theme’s folder. If functions.php doesn’t exist, create it.
3. Rename the function from parent_theme_function to child_theme_function.
4. Deactivate the parent function.
5. Activate the child function.

Your code should look something like this:

```
// Removes thematic_blogtitle from the thematic_header phase
function remove_thematic_actions() {
    remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_blogtitle',3);
}
// Call 'remove_thematic_actions' during WP initialization
add_action('init','remove_thematic_actions');

// Add our custom function to the 'thematic_header' phase
add_action('thematic_header','fancy_theme_blogtitle', 3);
```

In this example, the function thematic_blogtitle is being removed from functions and replaced by fancy_theme_blogtitle.

Comment: How do I deactivate the function if it is not already assigned to an action?  Is there a way to point the parent function to a child function?

Comment: You can deactivate the function with the snippet code above. That code should do everything you need to solve your problem, try it and let us know.